# fetching vault secret value using terraform

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault

I am using a vault server with consul as a storage backend and trying to fetch a password value using vault provider in terraform.
But it doesn't fetch its value. I stored my secrets at location secret/instances

**main.tf**

```
provider "vault" {
 address = "https://<IP_ADDRESS>:<PORT_NUMBER>"
 token = "118bb796-d715-8ce4-b987-7f354ff3f5a7"
}
data "vault_generic_secret" "mypass"{
 path = "secret/instances/password"
}
output "mypassword" {
 value = "${data.vault_generic_secret.mypass.data["value"]}"
}
```

When i run terraform apply it shows:

```
data.vault_generic_secret.mypass: Refreshing state...
data.vault_generic_secret.mypass: Refreshing state...

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Please suggest me something what i have done wrong over here as it does not fetch value of password from vault.

Comment: any output for `${data.vault_generic_secret.mypass.data}`? Check first if you can get the data.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes I checked output of suggested command, it also gives nothing like before.

Comment: then you need check if vault setting is proper or not.

Comment: ok.. i will check it then..

Comment: I checked vault works fine for me.. I am able to fetch secret value using rest api also.                                                                                           
                                                                                                               
curl -k --header "X-VAULT-TOKEN:118bb796-d715-8ce4-b987-7f354ff3f5a7" -X GET https://10.110.159.196:8200/v1/secret/instances/password
              
{"lease_id":"","renewable":false,"lease_duration":2592000,"data":{"excited":"yes","value":"pM0dularc"},"warnings":null,"auth":null}

Comment: Is key name `auth_token` or `token` in provider session? https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vault/d/generic_secret.html

Comment: In my case key name is password and i need to fetch its value from vault...i also checked that i am able to write any data to vault using terraform but not able to read data only.

Answer (score 8):

I also ran into the similar issue and found this post. In my case issue was with compatibility between terraform and vault. I was using KV version 2 which is not compatible with terraform v0.11.10.

Related Issue: [GitHub Link](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-vault/issues/140)

So i will try to write my answer with working example and environment details as it might help other people.

**Vault Version: Vault 0.10.1**

**Secret Engine Type**: KV Version 1

**Path**: srekv1/development

[image: vault secret]

**Terraform Version: Terraform v0.11.10**

- provider.local v1.1.0
- provider.vault v1.1.4

**Terraform Code to pull secret:**

```
provider "vault" {

address = "https://vault-myappXXX.net"
skip_tls_verify = true
token = "95XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}

data "vault_generic_secret" "srekv1" {
  path = "srekv1/development"
}

output Namekv1 {
value = "${data.vault_generic_secret.srekv1.data["Name"]}"
}
```

Comment: is there anyway to keep that vault token secret?

Comment: Yes either with that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65746460/how-to-assign-and-export-variable-using-terraform or another way using environment variable (I guess)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are giving wrong path, key name "password" shouldn't be part of the path. Something like follow,

```
data "vault_generic_secret" "mypass"{
 path = "secret/instances"
}
output "mypassword" {
 value = "${data.vault_generic_secret.mypass.data["password"]}"
}
```

Answer (score -3):

`vault_generic_secret` should be defined in a `resource` block.

You have defined it in a `data` block.

Ref: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vault/d/aws_access_credentials.html