# Retrieve keys and values from Vault using Terraform

Tags: passwords, terraform, hashicorp-vault

I would like to retrieve separately the key and value from Vault using Terraform.

For the following try, I am receiving that the value doesn't exists.

```
data "vault_generic_secret" "kv" {
  path = "kv/test"
}

output "kv" {
 value = "${data.vault_generic_secret.kv.data["Value"]}"
}
```

For an output as follows, I am getting the Key + Value in the following format: "key/value".

```
output "kv" {
 value = "${data.vault_generic_secret.kv.data}"
}
```

It's any way to retrieve just the key and just the value separately?

Thanks

Comment: What is they key and value inside of `data`? Note in the first example you are retrieving just the value as long as `Value` is a valid key, which it sounds like it is not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fetching vault secret value using terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47309229/fetching-vault-secret-value-using-terraform)