# How to assign and export variable using Terraform

Tags: shell, environment-variables, terraform

I want to get password from an third party server using API and then assign it to parameter store:

Initially I think I can use $TF_VAR_password as a bridge to achieve that:

step 1: create an .env file:

```
cat test.env 
export TF_VAR_password=< 3rd party API to get the password, say 123456 >
```

step 2: use Terraform null_resource to execute the test.env in order to export TF_VAR_password:

```
resource "null_resource" "get_password" {
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "source ./${path.module}/test.env"
  }
}
```

step 3: assign the TF_VAR_password (i.e. var.password) to the parameter store:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "abc" {
  value             = var.password  <---------
  ...
}
```

when I run the above Terraform, it shows:
Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "source ./../../../../aws/modules/test.env"]

But when I run `echo $TF_VAR_password` it does not show $TF_VAR_password as 123456.

If I run `source ./../../../../aws/modules/test.env` directly, I see $TF_VAR_password becomes 123456, which means the script itself is correct.

How can I fetch and assign the password from the third-party server to the parameter store?

Comment: Child processes (terraform) cannot change a parent's environment.

Comment: @John Hanley: is there anyway to assign TF_VAR_password then? Thanks. my original purpose is to fetch password from somewhere, and assign it to an RDS server which is launched using Terraform. To do that I use TF_VAR_password as an variable to get the password and then assign it to the password attribute of the RDS, and by running terraform apply, these things are automatically done.

Comment: In that case my comment does not apply. I thought you were trying to set an environment variable inside Terraform and then use that variable later in the parent  shell. If your goal is to pass an environment variable to a process executed by terraform (example local-exec) then @Marcin's answer is good.

Comment: John Hanley, I want to fetch the password from another server using an API (I set it as 123456 here just to make it easy to explain) and assign it to resource aws_db_instance.default.password using terraform and I think TF_VAR_password is a way to achieve that. but I do not know how to make it work. if this is not the solution and there is other good way. please feel free to share

Comment: I recommend updating your question to show exactly what you need to accomplish. Your current question is "sort of" messy.

Comment: @John Hanley: I have updated the question. is it clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HashiCorp has dedicated data source called [external](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) which would allow you to call your API, get the password, and then return it to your TF script for later use.

This would require you to return results in JSON form as shown in the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source#processing-json-in-shell-scripts).

Comment: Marcin: what is PASSWORD = var.password? I want to export TF_VAR_password so that var.password because 123456 but what will happen if you set PASSWORD = var.password?

Comment: `PASSWORD` is name of the ENV variable which will be present in your script. You can rename it what ever you want.

Comment: Marcin: I did not get it. I run your command, `echo $TF_VAR_tdb_password` did not show 123456 and `echo $PASSWORD` shows nothing

Comment: @user389955 Where and how did you run it? You current comamnd `source ./${path.module}/test.env` does no do any `echo`.

Comment: why do I need to echo? if I `source ../../../../aws/modules/test.env` directly I will see `echo $TF_VAR_tdb_password` becomes 123456. I do not get the same value it is because Child processes (terraform) cannot change a parent's environment, according to what @John Hanley said

Comment: I run it using module, I run terraform apply

Comment: @user389955 `environment` is only valid in your `command`. Not outside of it. I'm not sure what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have updated the question. is it clearer?

Comment: @user389955 And you can't do this this way. If you want to interact with external API, you should use and get the results back to TF, the best way would be to use [External Data Source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source). I will update the answer with this.

Comment: Thanks, I am testing and will update if it is helpful.

Comment: @user389955 No problem. Please let me know how it will go:-)

Comment: @ Marcin: Thank you very much. it works! Glad to learn the new knowledge. will be good for automation.

Comment: @user389955 No problem. Glad it worked out:-)